# How to filter record with condition blank field in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I newbie with phython, I have I have the following table TABLE.INFO:

```
ID_STUDENT|CURRENCY|ID_COURSE|STATUS
A12345|IDR|MATH|ACTIVE
A12346|||INACTIVE
A12347|SGD|MATH|ACTIVE
A12348||ENGLISH|ACTIVE
A12349|IDR||INACTIVE
B12345|IDR|ENGLISH|
B12346|IDR|PHYSICS|ACTIVE
B12347||PHYSICS|
B12348|THB||ACTIVE
B12349|||
```

I want to achieve the result which selects all field on TABLE.INFO with condition only having any field blank:

```
ID_STUDENT|CURRENCY|ID_COURSE|STATUS
A12346|||INACTIVE
A12346|||INACTIVE
A12348||ENGLISH|ACTIVE
A12349|IDR||INACTIVE
B12345|IDR|ENGLISH|
B12347||PHYSICS|
B12348|THB||ACTIVE
B12349|||
```

How can I achieve this using pandas phyton?
Can someone help with the script? Thank you before.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you done any research?

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure that output has some lines that don't appear in the input.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderCécile i have tried, with this script
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
student1 = pd.read_csv("student.txt",sep = "\t", header = 0)
student = student1.filter(currency == isnull, id_course == isnull, status== isnull)
student 

but with script above not working. please correct me if 1'm wrong

Comment: Why `sep=“\t”`? Have you tried printing “\t”?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work:

```
df
#  ID_STUDENT CURRENCY ID_COURSE    STATUS
#0     A12345      IDR      MATH    ACTIVE
#1     A12346      NaN       NaN  INACTIVE
#2     A12347      SGD      MATH    ACTIVE
#3     A12348      NaN   ENGLISH    ACTIVE
#4     A12349      IDR       NaN  INACTIVE
#5     B12345      IDR   ENGLISH       NaN
#6     B12346      IDR   PHYSICS    ACTIVE
#7     B12347      NaN   PHYSICS       NaN
#8     B12348      THB       NaN    ACTIVE
#9     B12349      NaN       NaN       NaN

df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]

#  ID_STUDENT CURRENCY ID_COURSE    STATUS
#1     A12346      NaN       NaN  INACTIVE
#3     A12348      NaN   ENGLISH    ACTIVE
#4     A12349      IDR       NaN  INACTIVE
#5     B12345      IDR   ENGLISH       NaN
#7     B12347      NaN   PHYSICS       NaN
#8     B12348      THB       NaN    ACTIVE
#9     B12349      NaN       NaN       NaN
```

For the opposite, you can do:

```
df[~df.isna().any(axis=1)]                                                                                                                                                                       
#  ID_STUDENT CURRENCY ID_COURSE  STATUS
#0     A12345      IDR      MATH  ACTIVE
#2     A12347      SGD      MATH  ACTIVE
#6     B12346      IDR   PHYSICS  ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import io

import pandas as pd

data = R"""ID_STUDENT|CURRENCY|ID_COURSE|STATUS
A12345|IDR|MATH|ACTIVE
A12346|||INACTIVE
A12347|SGD|MATH|ACTIVE
A12348||ENGLISH|ACTIVE
A12349|IDR||INACTIVE
B12345|IDR|ENGLISH|
B12346|IDR|PHYSICS|ACTIVE
B12347||PHYSICS|
B12348|THB||ACTIVE
B12349|||"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='|')
# if you care about the number on NaNs (> 0)
df.loc[df.isna().sum(axis=1) > 0]
# if not
df.loc[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```